# Gitorious: private mode for projects

Tags: gitorious

How do we make a project private in Gitorious? Does Gitorious support it at all? I searched around but couldn't find anything useful, except that Gitorious doesn't seem to have a private mode for projects. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible in Gitorious at the moment/maybe never. There is an outstanding merge request at the moment [here](http://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/merge_requests/115) but there is no update as to when it will hit the mainline (i.e. Gitorious.org).

If you want private repositories then you need to host Gitorious yourself - it's easy enough to install, and then make the entire install private.

Comment: I just finished the (wholly painful) gitorious install on my local server.  I set the whole instance to private in the config file, then created a repository.  While you have to be signed in to browse the repositories, It seems that the git:/ clone URL is still public, and anyone knowing the URL can check it out.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

If you really need private repositories, and you are looking for a free alternative, try [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). **Unlimited** private repositories, for **free**!

Comment: Yeah BitBucket's pricing is much better they only charge on the number of collaborators.

Answer (score 3):

Gitorious now has support for private repos. Get the latest version and add `enable_private_repositories: true` to `config/gitorious.yml`.  The Gitorious wiki page is https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/PrivateRepositories.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of Gitorious called YouSource which has private repositories. The repo is [here](http://yousource.it.jyu.fi/yousource/yousource) and there's also a detailed [installation guide](http://yousource.it.jyu.fi/yousource/pages/Installation_Guide) for it.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2011, there is a new supported [Private Repositories feature](http://blog.gitorious.org/2011/12/08/private-repositories/) being planned, keep tracking of it and support if you can.

Also note that, the private repository feature may be only enabled if you have a local installation.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.2.0, Gitorious supports private repositories. You should check out private-repos branch and you will be able to create private repositories.

More details can be seen in wiki page https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/PrivateRepositories